# Hadoop not all values get assembled for one key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have some data that I would like to aggregate by key using Mapper code and then perform something on all values that belong to a key using Reducer code. For example if I have:

key = 1, val = 1,

key = 1, val = 2,

key = 1, val = 3

I would like to get key=1, val=[1,2,3] in my Reducer.

The thing is, I get something like

key = 1, val=[1,2]

key = 1, val=[3]

Why is that so?

I thought that all the values for one specific key will be assembled in one reducer, but now it seems that there can be more key, val [ ] pairs, since there can be multiple reducers, is that so?

Should I set number of reducers to be 1?

I'm new to Hadoop so this confuses me.

Here's the code

```
public class SomeJob {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
 {
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(SomeJob.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/pera/data/input/some.csv"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/pera/data/output"));

    job.setMapperClass(SomeMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(SomeReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}

public class SomeMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

@Override
 protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String line = value.toString();
    String parts[] = line.split(";");

    context.write(new Text(parts[0]), new Text(parts[4]));
 }

}

public class SomeReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{

@Override
 protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    String properties = "";

    for(Text value : values)
    {
        properties += value + " ";
    }

    context.write(key, new Text(properties));
 }

}
```

Comment: r u using a custom partitioner ? Please share ur code.

Comment: Nope, the code is rather simple, like in wordcount example, but I'll share it...